# What is the recommended architecture for user groups in a react-native app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, nosql

What is the recommended architecture for user groups in a react-native app? I created a simple app with https://github.com/mcnamee/react-native-starter-kit which uses firebase and would like to modify it to fit my needs but am unsure of how to achieve this.

I want to allow users to be part of many groups if they choose (similar to group messaging where a user can choose their friends to be part of a group). So if there are three users user1, user2, and user3 there could potentially be group1 which contains user1/user2 and group2 which contains user2/user3.

In a relational DB setup, I could just use foreign keys to express these relationships but in NoSQL DBs, like firebase, the structure appears to be much different.

Is there a recommended approach? Are there example apps that implement similar functionality somewhere?

I am totally new to mobile app development and won't want to go down the wrong path right from the get-go, so any tips are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this.

there will be a `users` table in firebase which will have all user data. Every user signed up will be added here.

Each group will be added to `groups` object, with a members array that will point to user id in user table

```
groups:{
0: {name:'Group1',members:[3,1,8], image:''},
1: {name:'Group1',members:[3,1,8], image:''},
}

users: {
    1: {name:'user1', avatar:''},
    2: {name:'user2', avatar:''},
}
```

And you are right, choose the right db structure when u design the firebase/fire-store. The example i provided is just a pseudo code which u need to apply in your project.

I can help with Github links that make use of firebase. just run it once an d u can see the data structure they use to implement things better.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firechat

https://github.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-android

https://github.com/AleBarreto/FirebaseAndroidChat

Comment: So what happens if a user gets deleted? Then wouldn't you have to maintain a 'groups' array for each user so you know where to delete their membership from an existing group prior to deletion? In relational DBs the deletion can cascade.

Comment: when a user is deleted it will be go from members array as well for a group

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic a relational DB's design by [normalizing](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape/) your frontend data and using [normalized-reducer](https://github.com/brietsparks/normalized-reducer) to manage it. It's a higher-order-reducer that takes a schema describing the relationships, and returns a reducer, action, and selectors that write/read according to the relationships. Normalized-reducer is usable with React's `useReducer` and Redux, and it integrates easily with Normalizr and Redux Toolkit.